# How to use MetroFramework on windows forms

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to get metro U I on by visual basic windows form project.
I searched and found none comparative to this one :

https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui

Please Help me to get it running
I am able to install this package from nut get....
I am using visual studio 2012 and am new to programming so please be easy on me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in VS 2010 and it works really good after some hands on. First, I've skipped the nuget and downloaded and build the project myself.

In VS, I then added the contents of the MetroFramework.dll to my toolbox. At first it behaved strangely when I dragged/dropped a control onto a form, it didn't stick on the form instead it showed up in the panel below the designer like a Timer control does. To solve this issue I first manually added a reference to the MetroFramework.Design.dll. Then I got it working!

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I added metroframework.dll, metroframework.Design.dll and metroframework.font.dll in the the reference and it automatically added my toolbox metro item and then I changed the system.windows.forms.form to metroframwork.metroforms.form.